# YARN Summary for newly created HDInsight cluster shows 6 completed applications

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I have an HDInsight cluster (Standard Hadoop on Linux [HDI 3.2.1000.0]) which I newly created with nothin pointing to it. So no jobs are using this cluster as compute. Still the Ambari YARN Summary dashboard shows me:-

```
Applications
6 submitted / 0 running / 0 pending / 6 completed / 0 killed / 0 failed
```

I am very sure nothing is pointing to this cluster. None is running any adhoc job on it, in fact it just got created few mins back. If it's freshly created cluster why should it show 6 submitted? Is it referring to some internal jobs (like checks) that it runs by itself as soon as it's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambari runs a number of jobs to 'smoketest' the cluster when it starts up just to make sure everything is running well. These are the jobs you're seeing.